# Ajax Form Sending

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, forms

Okay I'm in way over my head as AJAX is definitely a weak area. I've got a page that needs to send a signup form via ajax to another domain to get processed and then return with a success / failure message.

When using the following code, the page just gets refreshed and nothing is sent?

Form Code:

```
<form method="post" onSubmit="return submitGetApp();" class="kinkast_signup"> 
  <input id="login_email" type="text" name="to" />
  <input id="signInButtonSubmit" type="submit" name="action" value="Send" />
</form>
```

jQuery Code:
$('#signInButtonSubmit').click(function (e) {

```
    //Get the data from all the fields
    var number = $('input[name=to]');

    //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
    //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
    if (number.val()=='') {
        name.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
    } else name.removeClass('hightlight');

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'number=' + number.val();

    //show the loading sign
    $('p.ajax_message').hide();

    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url: "http://video.kinkast.com/getapp", 

        //GET method is used
        type: "POST",

        //pass the data         
        data: data,     

        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        //success
        success: function () {              
            $('p.ajax_message').html('Success!');
            alert('Worked!');                    

            },

        //Failure
        error: function(xhr, status, e) {
            alert(status, e);
        } 

    });

    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;
});
```

Can someone check out the code and see what I'm missing? Also, to see it live, visit [this link](http://raul.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do ajax posts to another domain.

This is to help prevent such things as Cross-Site Scripting attacks (XSS attack).

There are frameworks available that allow you to do such things like [ACD](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/) however in most cases I wouldn't reccomend this practice.

**UPDATE**

Here's a working version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/4tMN3/

You'll notice a couple of new things.

Firstly I'm attaching the event using the propper jQuery event mechanism.

```
$('#mySubmitForm').submit(function(event){})
```

This is much more prefered than hardcoding the event in the actual form.

Secondly you'll notice the use of:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This is the propper jQuery way to prevent the default behaviour of the form (i.e. submitting) rather than returning false.

Comment: Not even with json? Bearing in mind I have zero exp. with ajax / json :) - Apologies for the silly questions

Comment: Also, shouldn't I then be getting an error message (using the code above) as opposed to a page refresh?

Comment: Regardless of what type is being returned, you can't make cross site requests like this. If you search around you'll find work-arounds but like I say, the restrictions are there for good reasons.

Comment: Nuts! Thank you so much... IF the code above was on the same domain, would it work or am I missing something? :)

Comment: It would almost work. There's only a couple of things you missed. Here's a working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/4tMN3/

Comment: Notice how I'm attaching the event. This is much prefered than hardcoding the event in the actual HTML. Also I gave your form field an ID rather than traversing through looking for an input with a certain name value. It's a minor change with minor performance gain in this case but it's a good practice.

Comment: One day, when I'm big, I'd like to code like you :). Thank so, so much for the help... Now on to convincing the client I need FTP access :)

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make cross domain json requests via jquery using a plugin. It uses YQL to return a page dump as a json request. Its not really recomended but if you really need to you can. Here is a link to it, there is a link on here to his github for the most recent version. I have used it recently for some testing and it all worked very well, Ill get a JSFiddle up in a moment.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

There is also a page covering posting via YQL:
http://www.wait-till-i.com/2009/11/16/using-yql-to-read-html-from-a-document-that-requires-post-data/

Example JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/M6X6n/1/

Comment: I missed off the main link from my original post, sorry about that!